# How to change default idle for python (Ubuntu)?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, ubuntu-16.04, python-idle

Okay, so I have python 3.5 on my system (Ubuntu 16.04). Whenever I open a `.py` file, Idle3 starts, thus pressing <kbd>F5</kbd> will instantly run my code.

However I need python 2.7 now for an assignment. In terminal I've `apt-get install idle` so, I can open idle and idle3 there easily.

My problem is, I can't change my `.py` files' default application to idle. It only sees idle3, so I can't open my files with idle(2.7) as default.

Tried to make an alias in ~/.bash_aliases as `alias python=/usr/local/bin/python2.7`, but typing `python --version` into terminal I get:

`-bash: /usr/local/bin/python2.7: No such file or directory`.

Typing `python2 --version` and  `python3 --version` works fine.

Is there any simple workaround for that?

Comment: Try to search in Google on how to change default application, maybe [this](https://www.howtogeek.com/117709/how-to-change-your-default-applications-on-ubuntu-4-ways/) ?

Comment: Type `whereis python2` on your terminal; you end up getting possibly one or more paths to python2. You can then copy-paste any of these paths onto your alias for `python` in `.bash_aliases`

Comment: you shouldn't need to `apt-get install idle`. There should be an `idle` that comes with your 2.7 interpreter.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga at least on xenial (probably other debian-likes too) `idle` is separate from the `python` debian package.

Answer (score 2):

Type `whereis python2` on your terminal; you end up getting possibly one or more paths to python2. You can then copy-paste any of these paths onto your alias for python in `.bash_aliases`.

Comment: Did this, but still can't see idle at default applications when try to set it. I removed idle3, now it wants to open it in gedit or something like this.

Answer (score 0):

[Change default python in Ubuntu](http://web.mit.edu/6.00/www/handouts/pybuntu.html)

This link gives you an idea about changing the default python version.